# How to compare two coefficent estimates in a multilevel model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

How can I compare two coefficient estimates from a `lme4` or `nlme` model?

In `HLM7` (software I'm more familiar with) such comparisons are evaluated with
$\chi^2$ tests. I can't find out what function in `lme4`, `nlme` or just `base` can do the same.

An imaginary example I'm working with, is a modified `sleepstudy` dataset - with two `score` variables added at level 2. The model being tested is this:

Level1:
$Reaction = \beta_0 + r$

Level2:
$\beta_0 = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}(score1) + \gamma_{02}(score2) + u_{0j}$

I'm looking for a $\chi^2$ comparing both level 2 coefficients.

Here is my modified dataset:

```
library(lme4)

set.seed(123)
score1=NULL
score2=NULL
for(i in 1:18) {
      x1 = rep(sample(1:5, size = 1), 10)
      score1 = c(score1, x1)
      x2 = rep(sample(1:5, size = 1), 10)
      score2 = c(score2, x2)
}

sleepstudy$score1 <- score1
sleepstudy$score2 <- score2

model <-lmer(Reaction ~ score1 + score2 + (1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
```

*P.S. if this kind of questions should be posted on SO please let me know so that I move it there*

Comment: Please don't cross-post to `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` and here, unless you've waited for a while (say a day or two) for an answer without receiving a response - although thank you for including the link in your cross-posting.  Where would you rather have your answer?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I won't do it again - as for the answer here is just fine. Where ever is easier for you. Thank you

Comment: you're basically looking to compute a **contrast** here.  You can do it by hand or possibly via one of many packages (`emmeans`, `contrast`, `multcomp`) - although I agree that  a description plus worked example here would be good (when I have a chance to get around to it)

Comment: Ben - I initially thought that I'm good to go with your hint on contrasts. Problem is - from what I read in `?help` for given packages I don't see any scenario where two continuous predictors, actually their coefficient estimates are compared. I might be missing something basic here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With suggestions given by @Ben Bolker on computing contrasts I found what I was looking for, although in an other package.

In order to compare two fixed effects one can use the `linearHypothesis` function from `car` package:

```
library(car)
linearHypothesis(model, "score1=score2")
Linear hypothesis test

Hypothesis:
score1 - score2 = 0

Model 1: restricted model
Model 2: Reaction ~ score1 + score2 + (1 | Subject)

  Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)  
1                       
2  1 2.8187    0.09317 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```